# jQuery not loading on Heroku, contained in Django static file, installed using bower

Tags: jquery, django, heroku, npm, bower

I'm having trouble loading jQuery on my Django app on Heroku. Heroku is getting the path to the static directory right, but it's not installing jQuery into the static directory for some reason. Here's some context:

I used npm to install bower, and bower to install jQuery into mysite/static/js, where it is on my local machine. I made a package.json:

```
{
  "name": "mysite",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "blah",
  "main": "index.js",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/username/mysite.git"
  },
  "author": "Firstname Lastname",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/username/mysite/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/username/mysite#readme",
  "engines": {
    "node": "6.9.5"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "bower": "^1.8.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js",
    "postinstall": "bower install"
  }
}
```

and a bower.json:

```
{
 "name": "mysite",
 "dependencies": {
 "jquery": "^3.1"
 }
}
```

I followed the instructions on Heroku for static assets: [Here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-assets)

I've linked my Heroku app to the Github where all the code is. I put mysite/static/js in my .gitignore file so that all the jQuery code isn't uploaded to Github. I expect that when I push, Heroku should get all that code and run `npm install bower`, then `bower install`, and get the jQuery file into the static directory. However, when I checked the logs on Heroku, it shows:

```
2017-02-15T18:41:14.351818+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js" host=mysite.herokuapp.com request_id=some-code fwd="some-ip-address" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=12ms status=404 bytes=2847
2017-02-15T18:41:14.343627+00:00 app[web.1]: Not Found: /static/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js
```

It translated `<script src='{% static "bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js" %}'></script>` into `/static/js/jquery/dist/jquery.js` correctly, but didn't install the jQuery file. What am I missing here?